# Mysql query select between dates php not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have the following sql query

```
 SELECT * FROM log WHERE Date > 2013-12-12 00:00:00 AND Date < 2014-02-08 00:00:00 LIMIT 10
```

Where the log table has a column `Date` in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

One entry in the database has a `Date` of `2014-02-06 21:48:10` which should be picked up by this query no? But it's not.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Are the `Date` columns of type `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quotes

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE `Date` > '2013-12-12 00:00:00' AND `Date` < '2014-02-08 00:00:00' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Knew it would be something stupid like that, thank you

Comment: you could have used BETWEEN

Comment: @Nouphal.M Then that would be different to the OP's logic. `BETWEEN` would be `Date >= '2013-12-12 00:00:00' AND Date <= '2014-02-08 00:00:00'`. See the difference?

Comment: @Phil, yes thats true

Comment: I had originally used between but as it was not working I switched to > and < thinking that would solve the issue, which it did not as the issue was with the quotes. I will be switching back to between.

Comment: Wow. Here I was thinking this was another stupid MySQL behavior, but it was actually doing exactly what I told it: Trying to use the result of two subtractions as a date.

Answer (score 2):

you miss the quotes

Do like this  for Date Range Selection

```
SELECT * FROM log  WHERE `DATE` BETWEEN "2013-12-12" AND "2014-02-08" LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Note; `BETWEEN` is not the same (it is inclusive)